# Bind on specific source port (RMIConnector)

Tags: java, connection, rmi, jmx

I am using JMXConnectorFactory.connect(URL)  to create connection to my server. I need to define a specific source port (wireshark shows that the source port is random every time the client is up) due to firewall issues. Any idea?

Comment: What firewall issues? Firewalls don't have  any business dictating source ports. There is no benefit.

Comment: @EJP It isnt the issue. We have a security problem to allow any port connect to the server.